# Git Merge - Unmerge Changes in Visual Studio and its Different Status

Tags: visual-studio, git-merge

Merging branch with resolve conflicts shows the different status in a file like below,

```
File1.cs [deteled in both]
File1.cs [added in incoming]
File1.cs [deteled in current]
File1.cs [both modified]
File1.cs [added in both]
```

what do they mean by this status? My visual studio is unable to open files with deleted in both statuses, what could be the course of action?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-resolve-conflicts?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

`both deleted` when `branch1` has a `git mv oldfile newstandard` commit, and `branch2` has `git mv oldfile newcustom` commit.

that case, when trying to merge `customBranch` into `standardBranch`, git will report a conflict on three files :

```
both deleted:  oldfile
added by them: newcustom
added by us:   newstandard
```

You can manually fix that :

#If removing `oldfile` is expected outcome : `git reset -- oldfile`,
#If keeping `newstandard` is expected outcome, remove other : `git reset newcustom && git rm newcustom`,
#If some parts of `newstandard` and `newcustom` should be merged : edit them by manually